# Set full width div with 2 levels of parents?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, widget

This is my problem : 
I have a container, with 2 divs (content & sidebar), in the sidebar there is a div and in the div there is an element (which is a wordpress widget).
I want to put the element outside the main container, with a full width.

This is a picture of what I want:
[image]

This is an exemple of the code :

```css
.container{
  max-width:400px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin:0 auto;
  }
.content{
  background:grey;
  width:60%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10%;
  }
.sidebar{
  background:grey;
  float:left;
  width:30%;
  }
.sidebard::after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  }
.element{
  border:1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta leo non rutrum laoreet. Suspendisse finibus viverra lacinia. In at auctor libero, aliquam ornare risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      <div class="element">
        <p>This is my element</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

I tried using position absolute, but it's not working very well :/

Comment: My intuition tells me this is a bad way to use absolute positioning. Is there a reason you can't put the element in a div below the two-column layout and still use the regular document flow (position: relative)?

Comment: Moving the div below the two-column is a little bit tricky (is customization of a WordPress theme), so I have to modify many files to do that.
The problem is when an update of the WordPress core, or the Wordpress theme I'm affraid of the code would be break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `position: absolute` like this, in combo with `display: flex` (as you need to get rid of the floats so the container size with content).

By giving the `container` a position, in this case `relative`, the `element`s `absolute` will relate to it.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
  position: relative;
  max-width:400px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.content{
  background:grey;
  width:60%;
  margin-right:10%;
}
.sidebar{
  background:grey;
  width:30%;
}
.element{
  border:1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100vw - 2px);   /* for the border */
  left: 50%;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta leo non rutrum laoreet. Suspendisse finibus viverra lacinia. In at auctor libero, aliquam ornare risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      <div class="element">
        <p>This is my element</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

You can use the floats as well, though it is not the recommended way of doing layout today.

By applying the *clear float fix* to the `container` it will work as well, together with the absolute positioning used in my first sample, the major difference is that the `elements` parent will collapse.

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  max-width:400px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.content{
  background:grey;
  width:60%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10%;
}
.sidebar{
  background:grey;
  float:left;
  width:30%;
}
.container::after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
.element{
  border:1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100vw - 2px);   /* for the border */
  left: 50%;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta leo non rutrum laoreet. Suspendisse finibus viverra lacinia. In at auctor libero, aliquam ornare risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      <div class="element">
        <p>This is my element</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Based on comments, here is a script solution, moving the element outside the `container`

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var element = document.querySelector('.element');
  var container = document.querySelector('.container')
  container.parentElement.insertBefore(element, container.nextSibling);  
})
```

```css
.container{
  max-width:400px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.content{
  background:grey;
  width:60%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10%;
}
.sidebar{
  background:grey;
  float:left;
  width:30%;
}
.container::after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
.element{
  border:1px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta leo non rutrum laoreet. Suspendisse finibus viverra lacinia. In at auctor libero, aliquam ornare risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      <div class="element">
        <p>This is my element</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I'll never thing a trick like that.
I'll try to include it on my code and I 'llback to you soon ;)

Comment: you may also take a look at display:table too and avoid calc and transform  if element has a static known width http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVyBbO ;) But in my opinion, .element should be taken out sidebar. Javascript can manipulate the dom ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Totally agree with taking out of the sidebar

Comment: You've right guys.
I tried many times to display correctly with CSS.
Then, I try to take out the element modifying the php/HTML but the theme is a litlle bit tricky.
So, if you have a solution to take out of the sidebar the element using JS I take it !

Comment: @AlbertoV Will post an update soon showing how to do that using a script

Comment: @AlbertoV Updated with a script solution

Comment: @LGSon thank you very much for your answer.
I just have a little problem with the script.
The div is correctly moved, but it has the "old" width.
To get the right width (full width), I have to click on another tab of my browser, and click back on my tab to watch the div take the right width.
Do I have to change the event listener ?

Comment: @AlbertoV No, change listener won't change anything, and as it works in above snippet, there must be another set of CSS rules that make it keep the other width, so by overriding those rules should be enough. Which browser do you use and do you have a link to the site?

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute sounds like the asnwer to me

Using position relative in the container, that way the element with absolute will take container as guide, and you can put the element where you want.

you also need to get rid of float left

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  max-width:400px;
  height: 220px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex; /* or inline-block in content and float right in sidebar*/ 
  }
.content{
  background:grey;
  width:60%;
  margin-right:10%;
  }
.sidebar{
  background:grey;
  width:30%;
  }
.element{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta leo non rutrum laoreet. Suspendisse finibus viverra lacinia. In at auctor libero, aliquam ornare risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    <div>
      <div class="element">
        <p>This is my element</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```